# Is ngCordova recommended to use with onsen UI for developing cordova application?

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, ngcordova

I am new to mobile development and exploring the Onsen UI for my work.
I also got to know about ngCordova. I see that Onsen UI talks to use angular js for development. 
Is use of ngCordova supported and recommended with Onsen UI? I am developing apps which are mostly for but not limited to Android, iOS but should be used on desktop with minimum tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Andreas for the clarification. Found that ngCordova is not the independent solution but have to be used with angular.js; ngCordova provides quick methods to work with Cordova. 
Ref: [ngCordova docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)
*Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since ngCordova depends on AngularJS).*

Answer (score 0):

ngCordova will work fine with any hybrid AngularJS application, so if you chose to use AngularJS for your project you can use ngCordova as well.